# how to solve difference color for same component in scss?

Tags: html, css, web, sass

How to solve difference colors for a same component in scss?

For example,  `border-bottom` of `nav-item` sometimes I will use `#F57C00` but sometimes will use `#FF5252`. I have three colors want to display based on different places in a website. How can I easy to make it? Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="true">A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">B</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">C</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">D</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">E</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.tab-container {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    // border-style: dashed;
    // border-color: #F57C00;

    p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
        border-color: #F57C00;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    .nav-tabs {
       border-bottom: 1px solid #F57C00;
       font-weight: bold;
    }

    .nav-item {
        .active {
            border-width: 1px;
            color: #F57C00;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #F57C00;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use different classes, each with different colors :)

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan Then I need to repeat a lot of times. Any example?

Comment: What do you mean by this "three colors want to display based on difference places"? You can have parent class for different place with different color. Yes you will have to repeat classes but not CSS atleast.

Comment: You can use SASS Variables e.g. $border-color: #F57C00;. Please check this https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables

Comment: @Veey 
$red-color: #FF5252;
$orange-color: #F57C00;

 .nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
        border-color: #F57C00;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
how to put it into border color easily?

Comment: You can also use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) (variables) if you don't need support for internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

//You can use three variables for colors so you just need to change in variables to change colors,

$primary-color:#F57C00;
    $secondary-color:#FF5252;

```
.tab-container {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    .nav-tabs > .active > a,
    .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
    .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
        border-color: #F57C00;
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
    .nav-tabs {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #F57C00;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .nav-item {
        a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            background: #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 80%;
        }
        .active {
            border-width: 1px;
            color: $primary-color;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: $primary-color;
        }
    }
}



<div class="tab-container"> 
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="true">A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">B</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">C</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">D</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">E</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Please refer link to see demo,
https://jsfiddle.net/jignashagpatel/ydjx08vg/16/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of variables in SCSS to store colours.
They can then be used without having to mention the hex each and every time.
It'll also help keep the code maintainable incase you wanna change a color in the future , you can just change the color assigned to the variable.